# Angular 1.2: Animating list items in parallel using ngAnimate and CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list and when I add an item to this list I wish to animate it into view and any existing items that are currently in view should also animate in parallel - think of a vertical conveyor belt going top to bottom.

I have the whole thing nearly working apart from the viewable items are snapping into place when adding a new item. Here's a snippet if code:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
   <div class="container" ng-repeat="item in items">
    .....
   </div>
</div>

.outerContainer {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.container.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
.container.ng-enter {
    top:-50px;
}
.container.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    top:0;
}
```

Any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of angular are you using and what browser are you viewing it in?

Comment: Angular 1.2.1 and Chrome 31.0.1650.57

Comment: are you including angular-animate.js and loading the ngAnimate module?

Comment: Absolutely, the item i'm adding animates down as expected, however, the existing items in view are snapping into place as previously mentioned.

Comment: Could you replicate your problem on a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vRGjRzZVazGBAuYxYtM3?p=preview ? The animations seem to be smooth for me with your mark-up and CSS.

Comment: To reproduce this issue use unshift instead of pop(). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Correction: To reproduce this issue use unshift instead of push()

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8wjk6lvU6WifTB58n1Bl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I believe your transitions have the transition property in the wrong location, it should read like this

```
.container.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but it's made no difference.

Comment: I suspect it works for the first item because it starts off at top : -50px and then animates into position at top:0px. However, animating the same item again needs a new start position of top:0px animating to top:50px animating the same item again would require a starting position of 50 ending at 100, and so on - that's probably why they are snapping. I can't be the first person to encounter this.

Comment: I've constructed a codepen to reflect what I think your problem is - http://codepen.io/ed_conolly/pen/ufmIL. Is that right? The other elements jump down because a new element above is created.